# Pharo: menu error

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I broke something in my Pharo image, but i don't know exactly what. Now when I try to file-out my package to insert in a new image, I only see 'Why you see this menu' and 'Debug'. If I run `menu debug` in the playground, I get `a FallbackMenu`. 
How can I fix this error?

EDIT: When I try to click on my package, The system browser is acting very weird an the following error pops up: [link](http://paste.ofcode.org/?edit=p3sGxNQASwijkvtwxeUsNV)

Using  Max's your code, i get 2 nil keys:

- The first one is a mistake in my code (I assigned a class binding to nil instead of a instance variable with the same name). But I can't edit this because I can't access it through the System Browser.
- The second one is ActiveEvent. I don't know where this comes from and whether this or the previous nil causes the System Browser to act weird

Comment: I don't know what is broken but all your code is in the .changes file so you should be able to recover from there.

Comment: Alright, but it is not possible to import (a part of) this file into a new image, right? I can just use it to copy paste my code in newly created classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is that you nilled a class binding. Inspect the following to get a list of keys and values that are nil:

```
Smalltalk globals associations select: [ :assoc |
    assoc value isNil or: [
        assoc key isNil ] ].
```

BTW: rather then attaching a screen shot it would help if you attached the stack. To get the stack trace, right click on the topmost entry in the stack list (the one that's selected in your screen shot) and select "Copy to clipboard". Then paste the contents (or at least the first 30 frames) here.

**Update**
`ActiveEvent` seems normal. I have the same. The second one is very likely problematic. You may be able to cheat your way out by removing the entry:

```
Smalltalk globals removeKey: nil.
```

If done a quick try and it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This is the stack trace [link](http://paste.ofcode.org/p3sGxNQASwijkvtwxeUsNV). Using your code, i get 2 nil keys.
- The first one is a mistake in my code (I assigned a class binding to nil instead of a instance variable with the same name). But I can't edit this because I can't access it through the System Browser.
- The second one is ActiveEvent. I don't know where this comes from and whether this or the previous nil causes the System Browser to act weird.

Comment: Such information belongs into your question. Use the "edit" link and add the link (or the trace directly) to the question.
See my updated answer.

Comment: This works! However apparently,  I'm not able to able to re-add this class. `receiver "new" is nil`

Comment: Did you recompile the method that contains the class reference? You probably need to do that.